# How to set radio button checked in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2.

I have a list and iterate it and display as radio buttons as shown below.  Now I want to set the check property if condition is TRUE.  How to do that in Angular 2?

```
      <table *ngIf="optionList">  
        <tr *ngFor="let op of optionList; let i = index">
          <td>
              <input type="radio" name="optradio" *ngIf=" (CONDITION HERE) ? 'checked' : 'non' "> 
              <label>{{op.option_text}} </label> 
          <td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: have u tried `op.checked` as a condition?  `*ngIf=" op.checked ? 'checked' : 'non' "`

Comment: Use property binding on the `checked` attribute: `[checked]="condition"`

Comment: tried the [checked] but it always checked the last radio button

Comment: The code example above suggests a misunderstanding (since resolved for the OP and several dozen others) of what *ngIf is for. In case anyone sees this and is unsure, *ngIf is used to determine if a DOM element (in this case, the <input> tag) remains in the DOM (yes if the *ngIf condition is truthy) or is removed from the DOM. It is therefore not the thing to use, and indeed [checked] is, as per the answer.

Answer (score 47):

try this

```
<table *ngIf="optionList">  
    <tr *ngFor="let op of optionList; let i = index">
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]=" (CONDITION HERE)"> 
          <label>{{op.option_text}} </label> 
      <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Online demo: https://embed.plnkr.co/jSht4Do3DzpoVQG2SAwl/

Comment: It should be a boolean not a `[checked]="(CONDITION HERE) ? true : false"`

Comment: just return `boolean` variable instead of return value `true`, `false` like `return boolVar` instead `return boolVar ? true : false`

Comment: It was wrong before your edit it. It was `[checked]="(CONDITION HERE) ? 'true' : 'false'"` which is not boolean. The new edit is fine.

Comment: @SadokMtir I think he was just acknowledging the thing you just called him out for. Go easy.

Comment: Can you guys confirm finally, which am I supposed to put?

Answer (score 7):

You can use it like this

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]="savedVal == currentRadioVal ? true : false" >
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can use the simple way**

```
<input type="radio" name="Availble" [value]="true" (change)="changeLogs()" [(ngModel)]="isLogsActive" [checked]="isLogsActive">

<input type="radio" name="Unavailable" [value]="false" (change)="changeLogs()" [(ngModel)]="isLogsActive" [checked]="!isLogsActive" >
```

Answer (score 1):

<input type="radio" name='{{prod.configurationItem}}' value = '{{prod.additionalCost}}' [checked] = "prod.isDefault == 'Y' ? true : false">
prod is object item