# How to set active class for md-radio-button?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How to set active class for element md-radio-button from Angular Material?

Comment: Check this to have an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059444/how-to-set-radio-button-checked-in-angular-2

You can use *ngIf to set the class based on the option selected.

Comment: Are you talking about `AngularJS` or `angular`?

Comment: See question's tags. About Angular 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/oL53j2Zqku3BkVVMzhNe?p=preview

```
<md-radio-group>
  <md-radio-button value="1">Option 1</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button #rb [class.custom-class]="rb.checked" value="2">Option 2</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```