# Give checked property to radio button inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I recently got into angular and was making something when I had a code like this

```
<th class="" scope="col" *ngFor="let rating of ratings">
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" [name]="param.paramId" [id]="param.paramId" [value]="rating" (change)="onSelectionChange(rating, param.paramId, coworker.empId)">
   </div>
</th>
```

Here If I put checked in the radio button it default checks the last radio button in the loop. Can anyone help me and tell how to default check the first radio button?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show the ts Code

Comment: @PrashantPimpale What part of ts code do you want to see? It has a lot of code.

Comment: `ratings` variable and expected output

Comment: you can use the `index` of the `ngFor` and just add the `checked` to true when its the first element https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059597/1113766

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Thanks for the help... Problem got solved :)

Comment: @JuanCastillo Thanks that works. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<th class="" scope="col" *ngFor="let rating of ratings; let last = last">
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" [name]="param.paramId" [id]="param.paramId" [value]="rating" (change)="onSelectionChange(rating, param.paramId, coworker.empId)" [checked]="last">
   </div>
</th>
```

or

```
<th class="" scope="col" *ngFor="let rating of ratings">
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" [name]="param.paramId" [id]="param.paramId" [value]="rating" (change)="onSelectionChange(rating, param.paramId, coworker.empId)" [checked]="rating.id === 5">
   </div>
</th>
```

Hope it helps :)

If those will not work, try to bind property to `[(ngModel)]="entry.id"` then:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.entry.id = '5'; // last value
}
```

Comment: Thanks the first one helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try following code for last checked.

```
<th class="" scope="col" *ngFor="let rating of ratings; let isLast=last ">
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
      [name]="param.paramId" [id]="param.paramId" 
      [value]="rating"
       [checked]="isLast"
       (change)="onSelectionChange(rating, param.paramId, coworker.empId)">
   </div>
</th>
```

OR

Please try following code for first checked.

```
<th class="" scope="col" *ngFor="let rating of ratings; let isFirst=first">
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
      [name]="param.paramId" [id]="param.paramId" 
      [value]="rating"
       [checked]="isFirst"
       (change)="onSelectionChange(rating, param.paramId, coworker.empId)">
   </div>
</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try set the index on the loop and add the checked property when index  == 0; for first radio to be checked and use let last = last; otherwise

```
<th class="" scope="col" *ngFor="let rating of ratings;let i = index">
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" [name]="param.paramId" [id]="param.paramId" [value]="rating" [checked]="(i === 0) ? 'checked' : ''" (change)="onSelectionChange(rating, param.paramId, coworker.empId)">
   </div>
</th>
```